# Bool array and corresponding title array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, boolean-operations

I have and array of bool values and array of titles and a string array, that have to show the users which product/s they selected.

```
array1 = ["false","true","false"]

array2 = ["apples","bananas","coconuts"]

selectedProducts[String] = []
```

I need to check if array1 have some "true" inside, and later retrieve it's index and append the product name at the same index to the selectedProducts.

User can select all of them, some of them or none.

Maybe connecting indexes of array1 and array2 is a bad decision. 

I check is !array1.isEmpty but then I have 0 idea how to make this work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip()` to combine the arrays and `compactMap()` to select those values which are paired with `true`:

```
let array1 = ["false","true","false"]
let array2 = ["apples","bananas","coconuts"]

let selectedProducts = zip(array1, array2).compactMap { $0 == "true" ? $1 : nil }
print(selectedProducts)
```

> > bananas

Note:  If `array1` contains `Bool` instead of `String`, then the closure passed to `compactMap` could simply be `{ $0 ? $1 : nil }`.

Comment: [`Bool` is LosslessStringConvertible](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bool/2428231-init) so your check can be strongly typed: `Bool($0) == true`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let res = array2.indices.compactmap { array1[$0] == "true" ? array2[$0] :  nil  }
```

While it's better to make it pure boolean

```
 array1 = [false,true,false]
```

Then

```
let res = array2.indices.compactmap { array1[$0] ? array2[$0] :  nil  }
```

BTW it's more better to make it a `strcut`/`class` item than having two arrays

```
struct Item {
   let name:String
   var isSelected:Bool
}
```

Then

```
let arr = [Item]() // fill it with your data
```

Finally

```
let res = arr.filter { $0.isSelected  }
```